# Need regular expression for C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to Regular Expressions and would like some quick help with this one.. We have addresses in a database like

S-01: 145 Main Street (Balcony)
F-22: 133 Washington Drive
P-55: 210 South St (renovated)

I would like to remove the S-01: and everything between parentheses

```
        string Reg = @"^[\d-]+$";
        Regex r = new Regex(Reg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match m = r.Match(rawAddressRow["BuildingAddress"].ToString());

        if (m.Success)
        {                
            //Response.Write(m.Groups[1].Value);                
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the regex's and code that you have tried to write and where that fell short?

Comment: string Reg = @"^[\d-]+$";
Regex r = new Regex(Reg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(rawAddressRow["BuildingAddress"].ToString());

if(m.Success)

Comment: Please add your code to the question rather than the comments and format it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following (Assuming that you always have one letter, a hyphen, and 01 at the beginning):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\w-\d{1,2}:\s?|\(.*?\))", "");
```

**Edit:** Updated to also remove F-22: and P-55:, assuming you want to do this as well.

See it in action here: http://regex101.com/r/nT0wG1

Comment: (\w-[0-9][0-9]:\s?|\(\w*\)) for any 2 digit combination.

Answer (score 0):

Removes 1-4 non line feed characters at the beginning of the string, followed by a colon and a space.

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=^)(.{1,4}: )", "")
```

Remove words between parentheses (including the parentheses)

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\(\w*\)", "")
```

Remove words between parentheses (leaving the parentheses)

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\()(\w+)(?=\))", "")
```

Combined solution (removes the parentheses)

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"((?<=^)(.{1,4}: ))|(\(\w*\))", "")
```

I'm making the assumption that you will be running this regex against each address entry individually.

Comment: This did it.. all these worked great, Thanks for Stack Overflow I will try to contribute to answer some stuff as well..